# Matplotlib pcolormesh with time on x-axis and boolean true/false as the colouring

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, matplotlib

I want a plot with the xticklabels as datetime-like objects and the colors to be `True`/`False` (`1`,`0`) depending on whether that time has been sampled.

The data I am working with looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

all_days = pd.date_range("2001-01-01", "2020-12-31", freq="D")
times = all_days[::10]
arr = np.isin(all_days, times).reshape(1, -1)
```

The plotting code I have is here:

Producing a plot without the colouring (but the correct labels)

```py
plt.pcolormesh(all_days, np.ones(1), arr)
```

[image: Pcolormesh without the correct colouring]

Or without the labels but with the colouring

```py
plt.pcolormesh(arr)
```

[image: Pcolormesh without the correct x-tick labels]

Ultimately, I want a combination of these two plots, the xticklabels of the former and the colouring of the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) optionally requires `X` and `Y` arrays which specify coordinates of the corners of quadrilaterals of the pcolormesh. So you need to pass a proper `Y` array:

- size 1
- from 0 to 1 as y axis limits

So you just need to use:

```
plt.pcolormesh(all_days, [0, 1], arr)
```

[image]